# Enabling 120 fps on mobile Safari

Tags: ipad, safari, settings, web-browser, mobile-safari

I just recently discovered that you can enable 120 fps animation on macOS Safari by following these steps:

1. In Safari, go to **Preferences** > **Advanced** and check **Show Develop in menu bar**
2. **Develop** > **Experimental Features** and uncheck **Prefer Page Rendering Updates near 60fps**
3. Quit Safari

Now when using Safari you can experience any webpage that supports up to 120fps.

However, I was wondering if there was any way to do this on iPad/iPhone? I use some animation-based webpages on a daily basis that support 120 fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same option as in your question is available on iOS: Settings → Safari → Advanced → Experimental Features → Prefer Page Rendering Updates near 60fps. This option is enabled by default.

Comment: Amazing! I would have never thought to look there haha

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific Safari setting for your question. However, in the Settings app, you can turn the ProMotion (120hz) feature on, on your iPhone/iPad.
(**Settings** > **Accessibility** > **Motion** > **Limit Frame Rate**)

Make sure you are using the supported devices for ProMotion:

- iPhone 13 Pro and Pro Max
- iPhone 14 Pro and Pro Max
- iPad Pro (2017 or later)

Comment: AFAIK this only allows to limit the frame rate to 60, not to enforce 120 in Safari.